# Launching a URL from an Eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'd like to have my Eclipse plugin cause a URL to be opened by the users' default browser. This seems like pretty standard behavior, but I haven't been able to find any docs on how to do this.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are looking for:

```
final IWebBrowser browser = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getBrowserSupport().createBrowser( ... );
browser.openURL(url);
```

Comment: This is the correct answer for an Eclipse workbench. IWorkbenchBrowserSupport doc: http://help.eclipse.org/stable/nftopic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/browser/IWorkbenchBrowserSupport.html

Answer (score 14):

If you want it in an external browser, you don't need to create one. This is the way:

```
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getBrowserSupport().getExternalBrowser().openURL(new URL("http://www.example.com/"));
```

Answer (score 8):

Use [Program.launch(String)](http://help.eclipse.org/stable/nftopic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/program/Program.html#launch(java.lang.String)) from the SWT API.

(Alternatively, Java 6 introduced the [Desktop](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html) class.)

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean launch an external windows (IE, FireFox, ...) outside eclipse, or opening an internal "[Browser](http://kickjava.com/src/org/eclipse/swt/browser/Browser.java.htm)" composite ?

Because on the internal side, the [org.eclipse.help.ui.internal.browser.embedded.EmbeddedBrowser](http://kickjava.com/src/org/eclipse/help/ui/internal/browser/embedded/EmbeddedBrowser.java.htm) seems to be able to define any kind of major browser.

To open the default user's browser (as an internal or external window) is a preference defined in General/Web browser.