# How to open eclipse internal web browser in my custom plugin?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, browser

I am creating an Eclipse custom plugin to run unit tests. When the tests finish, I want the Eclipse internal web browser to open the HTML result report automatically. How can I do it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to force the HTML to be opened in **internal** browser even if user as specified in preferences to use external one? If you want to use any browser then this will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/299806/launching-a-url-from-an-eclipse-plugin